# ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder

Tags: oracle, primefaces, oracle11g, geospatial, glassfish-4

When trying to persist an entity containing an oracle.spatial.geometry.JGeometry-object I keep getting this warning:

WARNING:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.

The object gets saved correctly in DB but somehow I can’t get rid of the warning.
If I bypass the addGeometry-method and set the shapePolygon-field to null (selected.setShapePolygon(null)) then the method executes without any warnings.

The ConnectionHolder-class is part of jdbc-core library but as far as I can tell it should be sufficient to include the ojdbc-driver on the GF-server. I’ve placed the ojdbc6.jar in both the pom.xml and in the server directory:
${GlassFishHome}\domains\domain1\lib\ext. 
This didn’t resolve the warning. I’ve googled the ClassNotFoundException but no luck here either.

I'm using a glassfish 4 server and an Oracle 11g DB along with primefaces for this application.

Any ideas on how to get rid of the warning?

Here's the call from the facelet that triggers the JSF-bean method-call:

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{gvkStoredKortlomrController.addGeometry()}" value="#{bundle.Save}" update="display,:GvkStoredKortlomrListForm:datalist,:growl" oncomplete="handleSubmit(args,'GvkStoredKortlomrCreateDialog');"/>
```

Here are the relevant methods in the JSF-bean:

```
public void addGeometry() {
    FileDataStore store = null;
    SimpleFeatureIterator iterator = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\tmp\\Primo\\");
        store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(store.getTypeNames()[0]);
        SimpleFeatureCollection features = featureSource.getFeatures();
        iterator = features.features();
        Geometry geometry = null;
        JGeometry jGeometry = null;

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            SimpleFeature feature = iterator.next();
            geometry = (Geometry) feature.getAttribute(0);
            double x = geometry.getCoordinate().x;
            double y = geometry.getCoordinate().y;
            int srid = 25832;
            jGeometry = new JGeometry(x, y, srid);
        }

        selected.setShapePolygon(jGeometry);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    } finally {
        iterator.close();
        store.dispose();
    }
    create();

}

public void create() {
    persist(PersistAction.CREATE, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("GvkStoredKortlomrCreated"));
    if (!JsfUtil.isValidationFailed()) {
        items = null;    // Invalidate list of items to trigger re-query.
    }
}
private void persist(PersistAction persistAction, String successMessage) {
    if (selected != null) {
        setEmbeddableKeys();
        try {
            if (persistAction == PersistAction.CREATE) {
                getFacade().create(selected);
            } else if (persistAction == PersistAction.UPDATE) {
                getFacade().edit(selected);
            } else if (persistAction == PersistAction.DELETE) {
                getFacade().remove(selected);
            }
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(successMessage);

        } catch (EJBException ex) {
            String msg = "";
            Throwable cause = ex.getCause();
            if (cause != null) {
                msg = cause.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            if (msg.length() > 0) {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(msg);
            } else {
                JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(ex, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the fields from the entity class:

```
@EmbeddedId
protected GvkStoredKortlomrPK gvkStoredKortlomrPK;
@Size(max = 64)
@Column(name = "KORTLOMR")
private String kortlomr;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "KORTLOMR_NR")
private int kortlomrNr;
@Size(max = 254)
@Column(name = "FILNAVN")
private String filnavn;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "OBJECTID")
private BigInteger objectid;
@Convert(value = "JGeometry")
@Column(name = "SHAPE_POLYGON")
private JGeometry shapePolygon;
@JoinColumn(name = "GVKORTID", referencedColumnName = "GVKORTID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private GvkGvkortdb gvkGvkortdb;
```

I'm using the following annotation on class level:

```
@StructConverter(name = "JGeometry", converter = "org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.converters.JGeometryConverter")
```

Here's the full stacktrace:

```
WARNING:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.glassfish.GlassfishPlatform.unwrapGlassFishConnectionHelper(GlassfishPlatform.java:124)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.glassfish.GlassfishPlatform.unwrapConnection(GlassfishPlatform.java:105)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle8Platform.getConnection(Oracle8Platform.java:104)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(Oracle9Platform.java:525)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.BindCallCustomParameter.set(BindCallCustomParameter.java:69)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabasePlatform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(DatabasePlatform.java:2435)
at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.oracle.Oracle9Platform.setParameterValueInDatabaseCall(Oracle9Platform.java:525)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:797)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.insertObject(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:377)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:165)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.insertObject(StatementQueryMechanism.java:180)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.insertObjectForWrite(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:489)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommit(InsertObjectQuery.java:80)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.InsertObjectQuery.executeCommitWithChangeSet(InsertObjectQuery.java:90)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatabaseQueryMechanism.executeWriteWithChangeSet(DatabaseQueryMechanism.java:301)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.WriteObjectQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(WriteObjectQuery.java:58)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWorkObjectLevelModifyQuery(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:108)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelModifyQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelModifyQuery.java:85)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1737)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitNewObjectsForClassWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:226)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:125)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4207)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1531)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:3168)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.issueSQLbeforeCompletion(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:352)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.AbstractSynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(AbstractSynchronizationListener.java:158)
at org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.JTASynchronizationListener.beforeCompletion(JTASynchronizationListener.java:68)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy263.create(Unknown Source)
at dk.geus.gvkort.control.__EJB31_Generated__GvkStoredKortlomrFacade__Intf____Bean__.create(Unknown Source)
at dk.geus.gvkort.view.GvkStoredKortlomrController.persist(GvkStoredKortlomrController.java:186)
at dk.geus.gvkort.view.GvkStoredKortlomrController.create(GvkStoredKortlomrController.java:123)
at dk.geus.gvkort.view.GvkStoredKortlomrController.addGeometry(GvkStoredKortlomrController.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

EDIT
I should of course have mentioned that already tried adding the jdbc-core jar. Both as a maven dependency and in the server dir (${GlassFishHome}\domains\domain1\lib). With the latter solution I get a ClassNotFound on com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.Jdbc40ObjectsFactory but when I add this (jdbc40-3.0.1.jar) to the server dir i get the following:

```
SEVERE:   java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.sun.gjc.spi.JdbcObjectsFactory.getDataSourceInstance(Lcom/sun/gjc/spi/ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl;Ljavax/resource/spi/ConnectionManager;)Ljavax/sql/DataSource;
at com.sun.gjc.spi.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnectionFactory(ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl.java:139)
at com.sun.enterprise.resource.naming.ConnectorObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ConnectorObjectFactory.java:156)
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.getObjectInstance(SerialContext.java:527)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:487)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:236)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.api.ResourceProxy.create(ResourceProxy.java:87)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:480)
at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
at org.glassfish.resourcebase.resources.naming.ResourceNamingService.lookup(ResourceNamingService.java:236)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.service.ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.lookup(ConnectorResourceAdminServiceImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.ConnectorRuntime.lookupPMResource(ConnectorRuntime.java:511)
at org.glassfish.persistence.common.PersistenceHelper.lookupPMResource(PersistenceHelper.java:63)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.lookupDataSource(ProviderContainerContractInfoBase.java:71)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.<init>(PersistenceUnitInfoImpl.java:108)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.loadPU(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:142)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.PersistenceUnitLoader.<init>(PersistenceUnitLoader.java:107)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$1.visitPUD(JPADeployer.java:223)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer$PersistenceUnitDescriptorIterator.iteratePUDs(JPADeployer.java:510)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.createEMFs(JPADeployer.java:230)
at org.glassfish.persistence.jpa.JPADeployer.prepare(JPADeployer.java:168)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:356)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
SEVERE:   Exception while preparing the appSEVERE:
Exception during lifecycle processing
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote in your question the missing class is in `jdbc-core.jar`.

It is not included in the `ojdbc6.jar`, so of course it can't be found if you don't include this jar in the classpath somehow.

It looks like you have two options: **Ignore the warning** or **Add the jdbc-core.jar**.

FYI this is the method which leads to this error:

```
/**
 * @return unwrapped GlassFish connection, null if connection can not be unwrapped.
 */
private Connection unwrapGlassFishConnectionHelper(Connection connection) {
    // Currently "GlassFish" creates a separate instance of jdbc connector classloader
    // for each application. The connection wrapper passed here is created using this class loader. Hence caching
    // the class will not help.
    // If GlassFish behavior changes, both reflective call below should be cached. 
    Connection unwrappedConnection = null;
    try {
        Class connectionWrapperClass = connection.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder");
        if(connectionWrapperClass.isInstance(connection) ) {
            Method unwrapMethod = connectionWrapperClass.getDeclaredMethod("getConnection");
            unwrappedConnection = (Connection) unwrapMethod.invoke(connection);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getDatabaseSession().getSessionLog().logThrowable(SessionLog.WARNING, SessionLog.SERVER, e);
    }

    return unwrappedConnection;
}
```

It gets called by this method:

```
public java.sql.Connection unwrapConnection(final Connection connection)  {
    Connection unwrappedConnection;

    if (PrivilegedAccessHelper.shouldUsePrivilegedAccess()) {
        unwrappedConnection = AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction<Connection>() {
            public Connection run() {
                return unwrapGlassFishConnectionHelper(connection);
            }
        });
    } else {
        unwrappedConnection = unwrapGlassFishConnectionHelper(connection);
    }

    if (unwrappedConnection == null) {
        unwrappedConnection = super.unwrapConnection(connection);
    }
    return unwrappedConnection;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Unfortunately I've not been able to add jdbc-core.jar without crashing the server when running my application.